# Trying to use class HttpsURLConnection in android studio, getting a error saying cannot resolve symbol HttpsURLConnection

Tags: android

I have a class developed in eclipse (on the same computer )  and I am trying to bring it over to Android Studio.  Android Studio gives me an error, it cannot resolve symbol `HttpsURLConnection`

On Oracle's website and it is said the class is in `java.net.URLConnection`, when I import it the line is greyed saying it was already imported.

code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;

public class cBitTrex {
    static int test;



    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Run code to talk to server on a thread
    // Every onunce in a while code to tal to server will freex
    // WEcall thread methed run and then wait for thread to exit with a time out
    public class cThread extends Thread{
        String reply=null;
        String url;


        public void run()
        {
            String ireply;
            error="";
            ireply="";
            try {
                ireply="";
                URL myurl = new URL(url);
                System.out.println("Open thread connection");

                // This is where the error is               
                HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
                con.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                System.out.println("Get input thread stream");
                InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
                System.out.println("Create reader");
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
                System.out.println("Creat buffer threadreader");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

                String inputLine;

                System.out.println("THREAD Read indata2");

                int t;
                while ((t= in.read()) != -1)
                {
                    ireply+=(char)t;;
                }

                System.out.println("finish Read indata");
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                error=new String(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Exception in getting data from API server");
                reply=null;
            }

            // Set return valur at end of thread so if thread call tiimout we will not
            // get any data
            reply=ireply;
        }

    };
..
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This class you are searching for does not exist, at least in Android. The one that is provided by the Android SDK is [java.net.HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). By the way, something you really have to take into account is programming for Android is not just like normal Java, it has some special rules. The correct documentation to search at is the one located in the [Android SDK official Page](http://developer.android.com/reference/index.html).

Beside that, your error can be that you were importing in Eclipse a Library that you are not using anymore in Android Studio.